# Android java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException error

Tags: android, arrays

In android, I added onClickListener to all buttons.

The codes:

```
        ArrayList<ImageButton> alfabebutonlar = new ArrayList<ImageButton>();

        alfabebutonlar.add((ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.harfab));
        alfabebutonlar.add((ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.harfbb));
        alfabebutonlar.add((ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.harfcb));
        alfabebutonlar.add((ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.harfccb));
        alfabebutonlar.add((ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.harfdb));
        alfabebutonlar.add((ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.harfeb));
        alfabebutonlar.add((ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.harffb));
        alfabebutonlar.add((ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.harfgb));
        alfabebutonlar.add((ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.harfggb));
        alfabebutonlar.add((ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.harfhb));
        alfabebutonlar.add((ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.harfib));
        alfabebutonlar.add((ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.harfiib));
        alfabebutonlar.add((ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.harfjb));
        alfabebutonlar.add((ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.harfkb));
        alfabebutonlar.add((ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.harflb));
        alfabebutonlar.add((ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.harfmb));
        alfabebutonlar.add((ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.harfnb));
        alfabebutonlar.add((ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.harfob));
        alfabebutonlar.add((ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.harfoob));
        alfabebutonlar.add((ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.harfpb));
        alfabebutonlar.add((ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.harfrb));
        alfabebutonlar.add((ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.harfsb));
        alfabebutonlar.add((ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.harfssb));
        alfabebutonlar.add((ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.harftb));
        alfabebutonlar.add((ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.harfub));
        alfabebutonlar.add((ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.harfuub));
        alfabebutonlar.add((ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.harfvb));
        alfabebutonlar.add((ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.harfyb));
        alfabebutonlar.add((ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.harfzb));

        ArrayList<String> alfabeharfler = new ArrayList<String>();

        alfabeharfler.add("A");
        alfabeharfler.add("B");
        alfabeharfler.add("C");
        alfabeharfler.add("Ç");
        alfabeharfler.add("D");
        alfabeharfler.add("E");
        alfabeharfler.add("F");
        alfabeharfler.add("G");
        alfabeharfler.add("Ğ");
        alfabeharfler.add("H");
        alfabeharfler.add("İ");
        alfabeharfler.add("I");
        alfabeharfler.add("J");
        alfabeharfler.add("K");
        alfabeharfler.add("L");
        alfabeharfler.add("M");
        alfabeharfler.add("N");
        alfabeharfler.add("O");
        alfabeharfler.add("Ö");
        alfabeharfler.add("P");
        alfabeharfler.add("R");
        alfabeharfler.add("S");
        alfabeharfler.add("Ş");
        alfabeharfler.add("T");
        alfabeharfler.add("U");
        alfabeharfler.add("Ü");
        alfabeharfler.add("V");
        alfabeharfler.add("Y");
        alfabeharfler.add("Z");

        for(i = 0; i < alfabebutonlar.size(); i++){

            alfabebutonlar.get(i).setOnClickListener ( new View.OnClickListener () {
                public void onClick(View alfabebutonv){

                    startActivity(getIntent().putExtra("harf", alfabeharfler.get(i)));

                }
            });

        }
```

But when I click in button B I get this error (log):

java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 29, size is 29

The logs:

```
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 29, size is 29

E/AndroidRuntime( 4367):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2325)

E/AndroidRuntime( 4367):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387)

E/AndroidRuntime( 4367):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)

E/AndroidRuntime( 4367):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303)

E/AndroidRuntime( 4367):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)

E/AndroidRuntime( 4367):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)

E/AndroidRuntime( 4367):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)

E/AndroidRuntime( 4367):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)

E/AndroidRuntime( 4367):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)

E/AndroidRuntime( 4367):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)

E/AndroidRuntime( 4367):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)

E/AndroidRuntime( 4367): Caused by: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 29, size is 29

E/AndroidRuntime( 4367):    at java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:255)

E/AndroidRuntime( 4367):    at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:308)

E/AndroidRuntime( 4367):    at com.example.xxx.xxx.alfabe.onCreate(alfabe.java:241)

E/AndroidRuntime( 4367):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5990)

E/AndroidRuntime( 4367):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106)

E/AndroidRuntime( 4367):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2278)

E/AndroidRuntime( 4367):    ... 10 more
```

I added onClickListener to all buttons in for loop for saving code. I think I get an error because in for loop.

EDIT:

I added this line in loop: final int index = i; I writed index to i. And the problem was resolved.

I hope you understand.

Comment: Which line did you get the error? Also, could you post the whole crash log?

Comment: @BachVu I get the error in the for loopb Ithink. I will edited the question

Comment: @BachVu I edited question and added logs.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What causes a java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException and how do I prevent it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5554734/what-causes-a-java-lang-arrayindexoutofboundsexception-and-how-do-i-prevent-it)

Comment: Do not access i inside the listener. When the for loop is run i is incremented upto 29 (28 elements) and exited. At this time listener is not executed. When you click a button i is accessed with value 29 and hence the error. Create a final map between button and label outside the for loop and aceess it from the listener.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside your method onClick(), it has a reference to your "i" variable, and its last value is 29, which is when it breaks from your loop, so when you call 
`alfabeharfler.get(i)`, its using the value 29 in all your calls, not just when you click on button B, and because of this you got that exception "IndexOutOfBoundsException".

Try declaring a new final variable inside your loop and use that inside your onClick method, something like this (I haven't tried this code, but it should work):

```
for(i = 0; i < alfabebutonlar.size(); i++){
    final int index = i;
    alfabebutonlar.get(index).setOnClickListener ( new View.OnClickListener () {
        public void onClick(View alfabebutonv){

            startActivity(getIntent().putExtra("harf", alfabeharfler.get(index)));

        }
    });

}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you. The button ran with no error. Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

Just make sure that both arrays (alfabeharfler and alfabebutonlar) and  have the same number of elements. Or event better, if both arrays need to match size and position, use a `Pair` object instead...

```
ArrayList<Pair<String, ImageButton>> list = new ArrayList<Pair<String, ImageButton>>();
list.add(new Pair("A", imageButton));
```

To access the a specific item...

```
list.get(i).first; //The letter/string
list.get(i).second; //The button
```

Comment: They have same numbers of elements

Comment: are you sure? If you're still getting and `IndexOutOfBoundsException` then you must be clearing your list somewhere else...

Answer (score 0):

Do this in your OnClick :

```
            //ButtonView arraylist and data arraylist size should be same....
            public void onClick(View alfabebutonv){
                 final int index = i;
                 // Ith position of buttonview should be less than the data arraylist size
                 // Add below check. i < alfabeharfler.size()
                 if( alfabeharfler != null && i < alfabeharfler.size()) { 
                    startActivity(getIntent().putExtra("harf", alfabeharfler.get(index)));
                 }

            }
        });

    }
```

Comment: I try now. I will write the result

Comment: I rtried. When I click buttons. I doesn't get error and result

Comment: Make sure you "alfabeharfler" arraylist and "alfabeharfler" arraylist should have same number of elements....

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
for(i = 0; i < alfabebutonlar.size(); i++){
            String value = alfabeharfler.get(i);

            alfabebutonlar.get(i).setOnClickListener ( new View.OnClickListener () {
                public void onClick(View alfabebutonv){

                    startActivity(getIntent().putExtra("harf", value));
                }
            });

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Do not access i inside the listener. When the for loop is run i is incremented upto 29 (28 elements) and exited. At this time listener is not executed. When you click a button i is accessed with value 29 and hence the error. Create a final map between button and label outside the for loop and aceess it from the listener to retrieve and use the label value.